# How to Replace Code Between A Tags Only When Link is Nofollow

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

Trying to replace nofollow text and image links with some HTML code (turning nofollow links into CSS/javascript links), been using preg_match and preg_replace for a while, but realised it fails under certain scenarios earlier today.

My PHP basic code (it's more complicated than this, what I'd been using pasted at the bottom) but this is the core code, the add_filter part is WordPress specific:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'st_nofollow_content', 99);

function st_nofollow_content($content) {
$content = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)" rel="nofollow">(.*?)<\/a>/i', '<span class="affst" title="tests" id="$1">$2</span>', $content);
return $content;
}
```

This is the simplified version, the code I've been using tried to take into account the issue described below, but it doesn't work under all circumstances so it's not ideal.

This works as expected as long as there's only one link or all links include rel="nofollow".

If there's a link with no rel="nofollow" attribute followed by a link with rel="nofollow" the two links merge together.

```
<a href="url-one">anchor one</a> blah, blah... <a href="url-two" rel="nofollow">anchor two</a>
```

Output

```
<span class="affst" title="tests" id="url-one">anchor one</a> blah, blah... <a href="url-two">anchor-two</span>
```

The output should be:

```
<a href="url-one">anchor one</a> blah, blah... <span class="affst" title="tests" id="url-two">anchor two</span>
```

I understand the problem, but not sure there's a preg_replace solution?

This code is what I'd been using and works most of the time other than when there's a mixture of links with and without nofollow:

```
if (preg_match('/<a href="(.*?)<\/a>(.*?)<a href="(.*?)" rel="nofollow">(.*?)<\/a>/i', $content)) {
$content = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)<\/a>(.*?)<a href="(.*?)" rel="nofollow">(.*?)<\/a>/i', '<a href="$1</a>$2<span class="affst" title="tests" id="$3">$4</span>', $content);
} else {
$content = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)" rel="nofollow">(.*?)<\/a>/i', '<span class="affst" title="tests" id="$1">$2</span>', $content);
}
```

Spent half the day on this and if I understand correctly it's not possible with the above type of code.

What should my approach be for only wanting to replace the code when

1st opening (a) tag : url : rel="nofollow" : closing (/a) tag associated with the 1st opening a tag?

Thanks

David

Edit: Looks like I should be using DOM which I'm not as familiar with. got this far:

```
function st_nofollow_content($content){
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $content );
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$alinks = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($alinks as $alink) {
$rel = $alink->getAttribute('rel');
if( $rel = 'nofollow') {
$alink = preg_replace('/<a href="(.*?)" rel="nofollow">(.*?)<\/a>/i', '<span class="affst" title="tests" id="$1">$2</span>', $alink);
}
}
$content = $dom->saveHTML();

return $content;
}
```

Doesn't work, throws out a fair number of warnings

DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity : related to $dom->loadHTML... line

Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string : related to $alink = preg_replace.... line

and has no impact on the links.

David

Comment: Yeah, you really should use DOMDocument for this.... this is a hairy mess, and I would personally vote for burning it and starting over. But, when I have to face something like this, I go for bash tools like `find` and `sed` - but, it looks like you need something with more surgical precision than a massive, cross-file find-and-replace...

Comment: _“Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string”_ – a DOMElement is not a string, and it doesn’t make sense to try and use preg_replace on it. When you have identified an element you want to replace, you should create the new “replacement” element and replace the original one using DOM methods as well (`createElement`, `createTextNode`, `appendChild`, `replaceChild`).